# I get a warning when initializing a class that says 'parameter value is not used' in Python

Tags: python, json, oop, initialization, typeerror

I have the following code that has one class with 3 attributes, and two functions.

```
import json


class Song:
    def __init__(self, name, artist, full_title=None):
        self.name = name
        self.artist = artist
        self.full_title = self.name + ' ' + self.artist


def save_json(list_of_objects, json_file):
    # json save
    with open(json_file, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(list_of_objects, fp, indent=4)


def load_json(json_file):
    # json load
    with open(json_file, 'r') as fp:
        loaded_data = json.load(fp)
    return loaded_data


file = 'my_songs.json'

song1 = Song('Roar', 'Katy Perry')
song2 = Song('Hello', 'Adele')
song3 = Song('Grenade', 'Bruno Mars')


list_of_songs = [song1, song2, song3]
list_of_songs_dict = [vars(s) for s in list_of_songs]

save_json(list_of_songs_dict, file)
```

As you can see, the object is initialized with three arguments (name, artist, full_title)

The code creates a list of objects and dumps it in a json file named 'my_songs.json'.

The json file looks like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Roar",
        "artist": "Katy Perry",
        "full_title": "Roar Katy Perry"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hello",
        "artist": "Adele",
        "full_title": "Hello Adele"
    },
    {
        "name": "Grenade",
        "artist": "Bruno Mars",
        "full_title": "Grenade Bruno Mars"
    }
]
```

I would like to recreate the list named 'list_of_songs' from the json file (named 'my_songs.json').

This is the way I have done it:

```
loaded_songs = load_json(file)

list_of_songs_from_json = [Song(**o) for o in loaded_songs]
print(list_of_songs_from_json)
```

The IDE shows a warning that says 'parameter full_title value is not used'

If i remove 'full_title=None' from the class initialization I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'full_title'
```

The reason why 'full_title=None' is in the class initialization is that in some cases, I want to define the object using 2 parameters, and in other cases (like when loading the data from the json file) I want to define the object using 3 parameters.

I suspect that there is a 'correct' or 'better' way of doing this, hence the warning. Any advice on how to remove the warning and achieve what the code already does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the information when `full_title` is not None. warning is coming because
for `self.full_title` you are using `self.a` and `self.b` which make each time if `full_title` is not `None`, it's value is not used anywhere .

so some modification to your code, where it check if `full_title` is `None` or not.

```
class Song:
def __init__(self, name, artist, full_title=None):
    self.name = name
    self.artist = artist
    if full_title is None:
         self.full_title = self.name + ' ' + self.artist
    else:
         self.full_title = full_title
```

Comment: I want to to the following: if I introduce 2 parameters when creating the object, I want self.full_title to be  self.name + ' ' + self.artist, and if I introduce 3 parameters when creating the object, I want self.full_title to be the 3rd parameter that I have introduced.

Comment: @ArmanMojaver this code is doing same as what you have asked now

Comment: Yes, the code works, but I get a warning from the IDE (Pycharm), which means there is a 'correct' way of doing this. I want to learn that way. Thank you